# jQuery - replace a list item with another from a element inside the first list item

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-selectors

so I have a list of comments that looks like

```
...
<li class="buried">
  <div>
    <a class="show">show this comment</a>
  </div>
</li>

<li>
  <div>
    bla blah..
  </div>
</li>
....
```

the javascript:

```
$(".buried").click(function(){

   $.ajax({
     ...
     success: function(data){
        alert(data);
        // here I want to replace the li.buried with data
      }
   });
  return false;
});
```

How can I do this?

I tried with `$(this).parents(".buried").replace(data)` and it's not working :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set the `context` parameter of the AJAX call to `this`:

```
$(".buried").click(function(){

   $.ajax({
     url:'some/url',
     context: this,
     success: function(data){
        alert(data);
        $(this).replaceWith( data );
      }
   });
  return false;
});
```

Since the `click` handler is on the `<li>`, in the handler, `this` will refer to the `<li>` that received the event.

I assume the `data` returned is another `<li>` since that's the only valid replacement. If you actually wanted to replace its content, then do `$(this).html( data )`.

Be aware that if you *do* replace the `<li>` itself, you'll be losing your `click` handler for that item. If you don't want to lose it, you may want to assign the `click` as a `delegate` on the `<ul>` itself.

Comment: thank you very much. I didn't know about delegate. I was usually  executing all the functions again after the ajax update :)